# Transactional and object mutation

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have an object retrieved from db, and updated

```
@Transactional
public void update(Long id) {
    User user = dao.get(id);
    user.setName("XXX");
    dao.save(user);
}
```

Meanwhile, the same record is being updated from outside of hibernate/JPA; lets say plain SQL.

```
UPDATE USER SET NAME="YYY" WHERE ID=1
```

What will happen?

Comment: If you have @Version field and it was modified then you'll get OptimisticLock exception. Otherwise, Hibernate should overwrite name.

Comment: @Justas That won't hold true if the native-sql happens after the Hibernate update nor if the native-sql update occurs and commits prior to the `#get` call on the DAO.

Comment: Yes, I had it in mind but didn't specify :)